# What do you call it when your unit does physical exercise as punishment because one soldier did something wrong?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, military

I served in the Russian military and we weren't allowed to use our phones when we were on duty. So whenever someone was noticed using their phone, the whole unit had to do push-ups, squats, etc.

In Russian the term for it is "качать", it's a verb, meaning to "buff up", our sergeants thought that if we don't get these rules through our heads, we will get them through our arms/legs. Is there a similar term in English?

Comment: "if we don't get these rules through our heads, we will get them through our arms/legs" Love that turn of phrase.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft.  In the military you *want* the members of your unit to watch out for each other.  Their lives may very well depend on it.  This kind  of punishment (we called it "mashing" in the Navy) is a way to get your unit to become self-policing and get everyone in the unit into the habit of watching out for their team members.  Think of it like a team building exercise.

Comment: @MichaelJ. Add _mashing_ as an answer, please!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Have you served?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I've seen exactly the same procedure applied on sports teams I was part of.  There's a fine line between "establishing trust" and "severe mental abuse."  Maybe I'm more willing to trust people even when they screw up than you are.  I don't see how punishing  most of us teaches the one person to get it right - if he's a sociopath the lesson will teach the reverse of what your Drill Instructor (or Coach) thinks it will.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft A military unit is not a sports team. People don't die when you miss a goal.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are missing the point.  It's that the procedure in question does not produce the results you think it does.  Period.  The criticality and probability of outcomes is a separate issue. (See Risk-Probability tables used in every project from printers to Space Shuttles)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm not missing the point, you're missing the relevant experience. :)

Comment: @Carl Witthoft , not to belabor a point, but you are looking at this backwards.  The purpose of such "group punishment" is not to teach the *individual* to comply with the rules, but to teach the *team* how to overcome an individual team member's rule breaking.  If a sports team does not learn to do this, they will lose the game.  If a military team does not learn to do this, they will die.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the US Army, **smoking** is a general term for physical punishment, although not necessarily *collective* punishment, as in your example.

A [Wikipedia glossary of military slang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_military_slang) has the following entry:

> **smoke** *(verb)*
>
> *(U.S. Army)*
>
> **Term to describe punishment of minor offenses by means of excessive physical training.**
>
> *Usage:* "The drill instructor smoked me for talking back."
>
> See U.S. Marine Corps term *Thrashed*

This seems to be an interesting niche preservation of an otherwise obsolete sense of the verb *smoke*.

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smoke):

> **smoke** *verb*
>
> *smoked; smoking*
>
> *intransitive verb*
>
> ...
>
> 2 *archaic:* **to undergo punishment**: *cf* suffer

...although note that in the archaic sense listed here, *to smoke* means *to be punished* rather than *to punish.*

Disciplining an entire unit, much as you describe in your example, can be termed a **smoke session**, as we can see in this excerpt from [a US Army document entitled *Corrective Training/Corrective Action Guide for Leaders*](http://cybercoe.army.mil/documents/IG/docs/CorrectiveTrainingCorrectiveActionGuideNov2011.pdf):

> Leaders must exercise good judgment in the administration of
>   corrective action. Corrective action may be applied to entire units if
>   appropriate (correcting an entire platoon failing to show teamwork
>   during Red Phase in a given training event by having them do five
>   repetitions of the pushup, for example), but will be focused at the
>   individual level whenever possible. Improper use can lead to
>   unauthorized mass punishment or hazing. Do not refer to this type of
>   administrative corrective measure as *"smoking"* or *"smoke sessions;"*
>   such references give the impression that these measures are punitive
>   or oppressive.

Urban Dictionary also has an entry for *smoke session*. Well, it has several. Here's [the relevant one](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Smoke%20Session):

> **Smoke Session**
>
> **A term originating in military recruit training, which refers to an intense physical training session, usually initiated as a form of punishment for minor infractions, where one or more individuals typically do rigorous physical activity until exhaustion and/or muscle failure.**
>
> *Bro, it was a total smoke session last night after drill sergeant Wilson caught Roberts sleeping during fire watch!*

---

Also, as mentioned in the glossary quoted above, **thrashed** (or perhaps *thrash*) is apparently a [similar term in use in the US Marines](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_military_slang):

> **Thrashed**
>
> *(U.S. Marine Corps)*
>
> **An extreme physical exercise routine ordered by DIs upon a recruit or Platoon for making a mistake which could last until complete
>   exhaustion. Puddles of sweat are often the end result.**

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I didn't necessarily want something collective, just the term itself.

Comment: @Happy Cheers, np. I learnt a thing or two writing the answer! Great question btw. For future reference, _single-word-requests_ are meant to include an example sentence showing how the word sought would be used. It helps narrow down the meaning required.

Comment: As a bit of a dissenting vote, ex US Navy here, and this is a term I've never heard with regard to collective punishment.  I certainly experienced it both in boot camp and on board ship, so the concept is sound.  I also grew up in a USN family, so I was exposed to military terminology from birth.  That certainly doesn't mean it's wrong, just not universal in the US Military.

Comment: @delliotg seems I was overly general. I'll edit and confine it to Army. (Have I got that right?) Any other terms in use? I'd be interested myself, never mind OP.

Comment: smoke, haze, why all the non-clear air expressions used for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 41):

**"Collective Punishment"** is the term you're looking for and it has been practised since ancient times, whenever a whole group is punished for the acts of one.

Examples of collective punishment:

> - During the finals of the national Dutch cup in April 2014, a few Ajax supporters interrupted the game by throwing fireworks on the field, and they inflicted severe damage to several areas of the soccer stadium. Although the damage was caused by only a handful of hooligans, the entire club was subsequently fined with €70’000, and the decision was made to ban all supporters—including the innocent majority—from attending the future games between these two teams for the following three years. [**www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5933726/)
> - During WWII: During the Nazi occupation of Poland, the Germans applied collective responsibility: any kind of help given to a person of Jewish faith or origin was punishable by death, and that not only for the rescuers themselves but also for their families. This was widely publicized by the Germans. During the occupation, for every German killed by a Pole, 100–400 Poles were shot in retribution. [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_punishment)
> - In 16th Century China: During the Ming dynasty of China, 16 palace women attempted to assassinate the Jiajing Emperor. All were sentenced to death by slow slicing. Ten members of the women's families were also beheaded, while a further 20 were enslaved and gifted to ministers. [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_punishment)

Examples of collective punishment are often found in classrooms, among the military, during embargos, wars, etc.

It's worth adding that under the 1949 [**Geneva Conventions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_Conventions), collective punishment inflicted on civilian enemies is considered a war crime.

Comment: It is worth noting that collective punishment is against the Geneva Convention and may be against the UN Declaration of Human Rights.  I say maybe because I am unsure whether special latitude is allowed in the military.

Comment: @Tuffy   It depends on which country you're talking about. "Under the 1949 Geneva Conventions, collective punishment is a war crime.  Additional Protocol II of 1977 explicitly forbids collective punishment.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Geneva_Convention)

Comment: The 4th Geneva Convention deals with the protection of civilians in a war zone. It has nothing to do with how the military treats its own soldiers.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  I never said it does.

Comment: I already knew this term, I guess I forgot to mention that I was looking for more of a slang term, sorry.

Comment: .... and even tho' it's a war crime, that doesn't stop any (USA) athletic coach from imposing it on his team members.

Comment: @Centaurus: You've described collective punishment as a war crime unconditionally, in a question about a military punishing its own soldiers, and cited the Fourth Geneva Convention as the reason. Whether or not you've explicitly said it applies to soldiers, you've very heavily implied it.

Comment: @user2357112   I will make it clearer anyway.

Answer (score 12):

In British military slang a semi-formal word used for extreme punishment of an individual is called a [Beasting](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/wiltshire/7463350.stm)
In general a group historically may have been ["fizzed"](http://www.word-detective.com/2010/06/fizzer/) generally subjected to "gravel bashing" (square bashing)

In Singapore a recent common term [“Standby Universe”](https://mustsharenews.com/saf-lingoes/) for a specific group task that may have to be repeatedly carried out from bunk to square, especially if something is stun (q.v. same link.)
An individual may be subject of "Blanket Party" as a form of hazing (bullying).

Comment: Groups can get a beasting due to the behaviour of one as well.+ 1

Comment: I was under the impression square-bashing refers specifically to drill on the drill square, rather than physical exercise.

Answer (score 2):

US Army usage:

An informal term for punishing a soldier with physical exercise is 'to smoke' the soldier.  It means to make the soldier exercise until he is exhausted, and then make him exercise more.

"The sergeant smoked me for for being late to formation."

"He used his phone, so the sergeant smoked the whole squad."

The connotation is that the sergeant is making the soldiers do so much physical exercise that they burn up or start smoking, rather than smoke them like a cigarette.

Getting smoked is not a light punishment.  To punish a soldier or a group of soldiers for a minor violation, the sergeant would make them 'do PT', as in do physical training.

'Do PT' normally describes ordinary physical fitness training, but it also refers to punishment if the soldiers are ordered to do physical training as a punishment.

"He used his phone, so the sergeant made us do PT for an hour."

You can also say "PT" by itself.

"If the sergeant catches of them with a phone again, he will PT them to death."

[enter link description here](https://www.businessinsider.com/phrases-only-people-in-the-military-know-2014-10)
[enter link description here](https://www.allacronyms.com/PT/Physical_Training)

Comment: As a hint on our site's expectations, note how [tmgr's post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/476898/167396) also covers *smoke*, but includes *authoritative references* to back up their answer. The supporting evidence distinguishes an answer suitable for EL&U from a personal opinion more suitable to a forum. Why not [edit] your answer to provide a reference for "PT"? For further guidance, see [answer] :-)

Comment: Please note that two of the earlier answers referred specifically to "US" army usage or to "British" military slang.  Would you please make it clear whether you are referring to US, British or some other country's "informal term", because this is the type of thing that is likely to differ between various English-speaking countries.